# How do I make the eclipse-cdt understand the word 'interrupt'?

Tags: eclipse-cdt, keyword, interrupt, analysis

I do a lot of work on older systems using the Infineon C166 microcontroller with the Keil C166 compiler. Interrupt handlers are functions with an 'interrupt' keyword at the end. Eclipse-CDT sees this keyword and marks the whole function as having a syntax error. I know I could turn the code analysis off, but I'd rather make it smarter.

Here is what an interrupt function prototype looks like:

`static void timer_callback(void) interrupt 0x17 using RB_CC23`

I would like to be able to teach the code analysis that the `interrupt` and `using` directives are valid.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm curious; what systems specifically have you worked on? If you're allowed to say.

Comment: I've worked in several industries. I've written for ignition systems, monitoring, and control for the gas and oil field. I've written stuff for automated manufacturing systems. I've done work in the automotive heavy trucking industry. I'm currently working in the payment industry. More specifically on payment terminals. As far as the type of microprocessors, I've worked on 6502s, 8051s, C166s like above, AVRs, ARM, x86, MIPS. Sometimes with low level assembly and others have full linux operating systems. I've done some of everything it seems at times.

Comment: [Comment 1 of 2] Cool—I've done a lot of experimenting and hacking with Brinks alarm systems, as I had one installed in my house at one point and was always curious about the technical side of it. (This is the old Brinks, called Broadview at one point.) Some of the panels they've installed are based on C166 hardware. I was quite excited when I read that the C161PI chip they used has a built-in Bootstrap Loader in ROM, and even more pleased to find the pin header for it conveniently exposed on the panel, I assume for use at the factory.

Comment: [Comment 2 of 2] I had already dumped the firmware from a broken panel, but that was by desoldering the chip, and I haven't managed to resolder one correctly. But using the bootstrap loader, I can send my own code to the panel for flashing ROM, and what's more, no matter how badly I corrupt the programming, I can reflash it, since the BSL is in an actual mask ROM inside the processor. — But anyway, back on topic (somewhat): do you know of any other C166-based devices I could buy on eBay or something and play around with?